# Possible to make a Windows installer that asks nothing to the user?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I want my app to install invisibly, from the browser.

No "Do you want to save file", no "Do you want to run this file", nothing!

I've notice Google Chrome, when installed from IE, almost mimics this, but still has a few steps. Can I go further? What are good resources/ books on invisible install?

**Edit: ClickOnce is this a viable option?**

Comment: @Bali C: Lol, no I am not. I just want to make it as user-friendly as possible. The user will accept to install it, in the browser.

Comment: That is a security breach issue. You are basically asking how to install malware. The user MUST be notified and do the action willingly will full consent. Any system that allows "invisible" install must be discarded and replaced. Invisibles updates are permisible if the user agreed at install time, but installation per se must never be invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask is not really at all about Windows Installer or MSIs, but rather a shell (or more specifically UAC) issue.

Once you have gotten initial approval from the user it is indeed possible to go about updates quietly. However, UAC was at least invented to make some user decisions more obvious to the user (keep in mind that MS claims it not to be a security feature, though, anymore).

The only alternative route would be through exploits of privileged software that is already running on a user's system, which effectively is a shortcut of the "initial approval" described above. But that makes it even more obvious that something is wrong about the approach you are trying to use - which looks suspiciously akin to malware/spyware and the likes.

Comment: @John Assymptoth: ClickOnce will still show a dialog to ask the user to install the application.